# Application of weak maximum principle.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, supremum-and-infimum, maximum-principle, poissons-equation

Fix any open, bounded set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that $u \in C^2(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$ is a solution of
$$-\Delta u = f \,\,\,\text{in}\,U$$
$$u=g \,\,\,\,\,\,\text{on}\,\,\,\partial U,$$
where $f \in C(\bar{U}), g\in C(\partial U).$ Prove that
$$\sup_{x \in U}|u(x)| \leq C\left(\sup_{y \in \partial U}|g|+\sup_{x \in U}|f(x)|\right),$$
for constant C depending only on $n$ and $\sup_{x,y\in U}|x-y|.$

Proof:

Based on the hint, I showed that the function $v(x)=u(x)+\dfrac{|x|^2}{2n}\sup_{y \in U}|f(y)|$ is subharmonic. Then applying the weak maximum principle, we get
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x \in U} |v(x)| \leq  \sup_{x \in \partial U} |u(x)|+ \dfrac{1}{2n}\sup_{x \in \partial U} |x|^2.\sup_{y\in U}|f(y)|
\end{align*}

I don't know how to end up with the final inequality. Furthermore, I think we have the constant $C$ will depend on $n$ and $sup_{x \in \partial U} |x|^2$, how it could be depend on $\sup_{x,y\in U}|x-y|?$

Could you please give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Since $v$ is subharmonic, from the maximum principle you have that $$ u(x)+ \frac 1{2n} \vert x\vert^2\sup_{\Omega}\vert f\vert =v\leq\sup_\Omega v = \sup_{\partial \Omega} v \leq \sup_{\partial \Omega}\vert u \vert + \frac 1{2n} \big ( \sup_{x\in \Omega} \vert x\vert\big )^2\sup_{\Omega}\vert f\vert \qquad \text{for all } x\in \Omega.$$ Since $u=g$ on $\partial \Omega$, this gives $$u(x) \leq \sup_{\partial \Omega}\vert g \vert + \frac 1{2n} \big ( \sup_{x\in \Omega} \vert x\vert\big )^2\sup_{\Omega}\vert f\vert-\frac 1{2n} \vert x\vert^2\sup_{\Omega}\vert f\vert \leq \sup_{\partial \Omega}\vert g \vert + \frac 1{n} \big ( \sup_{x\in \Omega} \vert x\vert\big )^2\sup_{\Omega}\vert f\vert. \tag{$\ast$} $$ This implies that $$ \sup_\Omega u \leq C \big ( \sup_{\partial \Omega}\vert g \vert + \sup_{\Omega}\vert f\vert\big ) $$ with $$C=\frac 1{n} \big ( \sup_{x\in \Omega} \vert x\vert\big )^2+1. $$ Applying ($\ast$) to $-u$ further implies that $$ \sup_\Omega \vert u\vert \leq C \big ( \sup_{\partial \Omega}\vert g \vert + \sup_{\Omega}\vert f\vert\big )$$ with $C$ as before.

Now this is almost what you want: the only issue is that you want $C$ to depend on $\operatorname{diam}\Omega := \sup_{x,y\in \Omega}\vert x-y\vert$ instead of $\sup_{x\in \Omega } \vert x \vert $ as we obtained above. To do this, try replacing the $\vert x \vert^2$ in your guess with $\vert x- a\vert^2$ where $a\in \Omega$ is arbitrary. Then repeat the arguments exactly as above, using that $$\sup_{x\in \Omega } \vert x -a\vert \leq \operatorname{diam} \Omega $$ to obtain the desired inequality with $$C=\frac 1 n (\operatorname{diam} \Omega)^2 +1 .$$

Comment: I think your work is great, but I have a question about why can you change $\sup_{x \in \partial  \Omega}|x|^2$ into $\left(\sup_{x \in \Omega}|x|\right)^2$. Since the weak maximum principle apply on the boundary.

Comment: For all $x\in \partial \Omega$, $\vert x \vert \leq \max_{x\in \overline \Omega} \vert x \vert = \sup_{x\in \Omega} \vert x \vert$. Hence, $\sup_{x\in \partial \Omega} \vert x \vert^2 \leq (\sup_{x\in \Omega} \vert x \vert )^2$

Comment: I think $\max_{x \in \overline{\Omega}} |x| \geq \sup_{x \in \Omega}|x|$, doesn’t it?

Comment: Since $x\mapsto \vert x \vert$ is continuous, they are the same. Let $\bar x \in \overline \Omega$ be such that $\vert \bar x\vert = \max_{\overline \Omega} \vert x\vert $ and $\{ x_k\} \subset \Omega$ with $x_k \to \bar x$. Then $\max_{\overline \Omega } \vert x \vert =\vert \bar x \vert = \lim_{k\to + \infty} \vert x_k\vert \leq \sup_{\Omega} \vert x \vert$

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You’re welcome:) If this answers your question then you should mark this answer with a tick (and upvote if you want)

Comment: Oh, I voted up but I don't have enough reputation so I am really sorry about that.